# Asp.NET C# Session Variables from class to handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, session, handler

I am trying, to avoid using querystrings, to use a session variable to pass the desired value.
I'm doing this from a class to a handler.

In the class I use:

```
HttpContext.Session["name"] = "Value";
```

In the handler I use:

```
var name = context.Session["name"];
```

I have already added `IReadOnlySessionState` or `IRequiresSessionState` but the session variables remain null.

Some help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating new context again. you should use the same session using `HttpContext.Current`.
   Try Code Like below and Refer Comments what i have added below.

```
    string firstName = "Jeff";
    string lastName = "Smith";
    string city = "Seattle";

    // Save to session state in a Web Forms page class.
    Session["FirstName"] = firstName;
    Session["LastName"] = lastName;
    Session["City"] = city;

    // Read from session state in a Web Forms page class.
    firstName = (string)(Session["FirstName"]);
    lastName = (string)(Session["LastName"]);
    city = (string)(Session["City"]);

    // Outside of Web Forms page class, use HttpContext.Current.
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Session["FirstName"] = firstName;
    firstName = (string)(context.Session["FirstName"]);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer... but it's not working...
I'm setting the value in the class but, on the handler, it's still null.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, however others may find this useful.

Try passing HttpContext.Current as a parameter to the routine in your common class.

Code from the web forms class:

```
protected void SetSessionValue()
{
    var CurrentSession = HttpContext.Current;

    oCommonClass.cSetSessionValue(CurrentSession);

    var SessionValue = Session("SessionValue");
}
```

Code from the common class:

```
public void cSetSessionValue(object cCurrentSession)
{
    var cSessionValue = "New Value";
    cCurrentSession.Session("SessionValue") = cSessionValue;
}
```